# Ansible telnet without username login

Tags: ansible, telnet, cisco

I need to connect to cisco devices with ansible telnet module (I can't enable SSH).
In all the tutorial I found on the web, everyone is specifying a login username and a password for authenticating in telnet.

But my router doesn't have a username need, the auth prompt start directly with the mesage :

```
Password:
```

Here's my files :

inventory.yml :

```
[cisco]
test ip_address=xxx.yyy.zzz

[cisco:vars]
password=test
password_enable=test
```

plays/cisco.yml :

```
---

- hosts: cisco
  connection: local
  roles:
    - role: cisco-telnet
```

roles/cisco-telnet/tasks/main.yml :

```
---
- name: Telnet test
  telnet:
    host: "{{ ip_address }}"
    port: 23
    password_prompt: "Password:"
    password: "{{ password }}"
    prompts:
      - '[>|#]'
    command:
      - enable
      - "{{ password_enable }}"
      - show running-config
```

I got an error message everytime :

```
FAILED! => {
    "msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.",
    "stdout": ""
}
```

How can I use telnet module without specifying a username ? Someone already did that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Studying the source code of the [telnet module](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.7/lib/ansible/plugins/action/telnet.py) and reading the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/telnet_module.html) I assume the follwing behaviour:

> If the `password` is empty then no `password prompt` is expected.

It follows that you can use the `login prompt` for the `password`. Somewhat strange, so I guess the following code snippet should work:

```
- name: Telnet test
  telnet:
    host: "{{ ip_address }}"
    port: 23
    login_prompt: "Password:"
    user: "{{ password }}"
    prompts:
      - '[>|#]'
    command:
      - enable
      - "{{ password_enable }}"
      - show running-config
```

I can't test it because I do not have a telnet server anymore, you are 20 years late ;-)